# UISwitch animation issue

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiswitch

`UISwithch` manage like a radio button. I have three buttons and need to buttons like a radio button if one switch is on then rest set off. Issue in animation. Please check link for animation

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_UHi0hvLR2SaC6l-TAZHS4vqn54tS_bq/view?usp=sharing

Here I update my code,Functionality is only one switch can on at a time, if one switch getting on rest two switch off.

```
- (IBAction)switchOnPopular:(id)sender
{
    if(![_PopularSwitch isOn])
    {
        [_PopularSwitch setThumbTintColor:APP_COLOR()];
        _lblPopular.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        [_PopularSwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];
    }

    if([_AtoZSwitch isOn])
    {
        [_AtoZSwitch setThumbTintColor:FOLLOWING_COLOR()];
        _lblAtoz.backgroundColor=SWITCH_OFF_LBL_COLR();
        [_AtoZSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }

    if([_nearMeSwitch isOn])
    {
        [_nearMeSwitch setThumbTintColor:FOLLOWING_COLOR()];
        _lblnearme.backgroundColor=SWITCH_OFF_LBL_COLR();
        [_nearMeSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }
    strFilterOption = BUSINESS_FILTER_TYPE_MOST_POPULAR;
}

- (IBAction)switchOnNearMe:(id)sender
{
    if(![_nearMeSwitch isOn])
    {
        [_nearMeSwitch setThumbTintColor:APP_COLOR()];
        _lblnearme.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        [_nearMeSwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];
    }

    if([_PopularSwitch isOn])
    {
        [_PopularSwitch setThumbTintColor:FOLLOWING_COLOR()];
        _lblPopular.backgroundColor=SWITCH_OFF_LBL_COLR();
        [_PopularSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }

    if([_AtoZSwitch isOn])
    {
        [_AtoZSwitch setThumbTintColor:FOLLOWING_COLOR()];
        _lblAtoz.backgroundColor=SWITCH_OFF_LBL_COLR();
        [_AtoZSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }
    strFilterOption = BUSINESS_FILTER_TYPE_NEARBY;
}

- (IBAction)switchOnAtoZ:(id)sender
{
    if(![_AtoZSwitch isOn])
    {
        [_AtoZSwitch setThumbTintColor:APP_COLOR()];
        _lblAtoz.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        [_AtoZSwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];
    }

    if([_PopularSwitch isOn])
    {
        [_PopularSwitch setThumbTintColor:FOLLOWING_COLOR()];
        _lblPopular.backgroundColor=SWITCH_OFF_LBL_COLR();
        [_PopularSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }

    if([_nearMeSwitch isOn])
    {
        [_nearMeSwitch setThumbTintColor:FOLLOWING_COLOR()];
        _lblnearme.backgroundColor=SWITCH_OFF_LBL_COLR();
        [_nearMeSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }
    strFilterOption = BUSINESS_FILTER_TYPE_ALPHABETIC;
}
```

Comment: I see no reason at all why that should happen with the code you shared. Can you share more, like your initialization function of these UISwitches? Also on a whim try moving the setOn to be after the colors have been set, don't think it would make a difference but worth testing

Comment: I have set comment on colour changing code after that it's working fine. Can you please suggest me how to change background colour and tint colour with managing animation.

Comment: Not sure why changing the colors is messing up the animation block, I've added an answer for how to change the colors first THEN call the animation block 0.01s later using GCD, that should patch this UI bug that Apple has.

Comment: What else are you doing? it seems to me that you are also doing something with your view hierarchy, e.g. adding/removing constraints or re-adding views.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw I's client requirement change colour when switch on or switch off

Comment: @Sulthan I am not doing any other things like adding/removing constraints

Comment: @RahulParikh How do you set the other switches to off when one is set is turned on? Where is that code?

Comment: @RahulParikh Did you try my GCD solution in my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why changing the colors is causing this animation issue for you, but I would recommend changing them first then calling the animation after UI updates via GCD w/ delay

```
[_nearMeSwitch setThumbTintColor:FOLLOWING_COLOR()];
_lblnearme.backgroundColor=SWITCH_OFF_LBL_COLR();
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.01f*NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [_nearMeSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
});
```